# CPU spike when overriding Sitecore's link provider

Tags: sitecore

Our CPU spikes after overriding Sitecore's link provider. We are overriding GetItemUrl to get the alias url for certain types of templates, and it goes up to 80% of CPU when the only thing hitting the website is the keepalive page.

This is the config line for the default link provider that works fine:

```
<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
```

This is the config line for our custom link provider that spikes the CPU:

```
<add name="sitecore"
type="Library.Pipelines.CustomLinkProvider, Library"
addAspxExtension="false"
alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false"
encodeNames="true"
languageEmbedding="never"
languageLocation="filePath"
shortenUrls="true"
useDisplayName="false" />
```

The CustomLinkProvider class:

```
public class CustomLinkProvider : LinkProvider
{
    public override string GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
    {
        // check if item is factsheet or story, if it is then get the alias url
        if (item.TemplateID == ItemConstants.Pages.Factsheet.TemplateID 
        || item.TemplateID == ItemConstants.Pages.Story.TemplateID)
        {
            if (Sitecore.Context.Database != null)
            {
                if (SitecoreHelpers.HasAlias(item, Sitecore.Context.Database))
                {
                    Item alias = SitecoreHelpers.GetAlias(item, Sitecore.Context.Database);
                    string friendlyUrl = alias.Name;
                    return friendlyUrl;
                }
            }
        }
        return base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
    }
}
```

This is the GetAlias function:

```
public static Item GetAlias(Item currentItem, Database database)
{
    Item aliasFolder = database.GetItem(ItemConstants.Common.SystemAliasFolder);

    Item alias =
        aliasFolder.Children.FirstOrDefault(
        x => ((LinkField) x.Fields["Linked item"]).TargetID == currentItem.ID);

    return alias;
}
```

Anyone have any idea why this would spike the CPU? There's around 600 aliases at the moment, but I wouldn't think that would cause such a big spike.

Comment: Y U NO USE A PROFILER?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that it is the combination of HasAlias and GetAlias that's causing your problem. Iterating through 600 sitecore items could indeed cause a CPU spike, particularly with there potentially being multiple calls to the link provider. A profiler such as ANTS would allow you to confirm.

I would suggest that instead of doing this on every call, that you read all aliases and cache a data structure relating your items to their aliases. You'll need to clear the cache when aliases are added, edited, or deleted, but this should save you a ton of CPU cycles.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think that would have such a massive impact but will cache it instead. :)

Comment: I agree, a great solution indeed!